# c++ pointer always on the same address even if not deleted

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am playing with C++ pointers. I allocated memory to a pointer but I didn't free it afterwards. The next time I ran the program the pointer resides on the same address - why? Shouldn't OS see that address as occupied thus generating a memory leak?

```
int* a = new int[1]; //or (int*) malloc(1);
cout << &a << endl; //always 0x28fe98
```

Comment: The term "address" doesn't mean what you seem to think it means.

Comment: And the address inside `a` is just `a` not `&a`, so try `cout << (void*)a << endl;`

Comment: And memory leak is concerned when the program is running. Once you exit the program the OS takes the memory. So it is not occupied anymore. Leaks are more concerning for programs which run for a prolonged interval of time. Possibly repeatedly processing different but similar inputs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A few misunderstandings...

1. The expression `&a` is the address of the variable `a`, that is, the address of the pointer, of type pointer-to-pointer-to-int. It does not matter the value of `a` itself, that is, whether it is initialized or not, its address is the same. You probably want to do `cout << a << std::endl;`
2. For each run of the program the OS allocates a whole new address space, and frees it when the program finishes, so even if you don't free the memory it will be freed when the program finishes. And even if the program does not finish, each process has its own address space, so the memory allocated in one does not affect the memory of the other.
3. It is only natural that several runs of the same program yields more or less the same addresses, unless some form of virtual space randomization is used (for security purposes).

Anyway, remember that in C++ there are basically 3 types of memory: static (global variables), automatic (local variables) and dynamic (new'ed objects). In your example, `a` (with address `&a`) is automatic or static, not clear from the context, but the integer pointed to by `a` (address `a`) is dynamic. You may want to play with all 3 of them to see how they are different.

A particularly interesting experiment is the address of a local variable in a recursive function:

```
void rec(int x)
{
    cout << x << ": " << &x << endl;
    if ( x > 0)
        rec(x - 1);
}
```

Comment: +1: excellent and thorough answer, explains all the issues concisely.

Comment: @NikBougalis I was going to write the same, +1.

Answer (score 6):

If you run the program again, that means the previous run ended. Which means the OS reclaimed the memory. Memory leaks don't mean that the memory is forever reserved to your app, even after it ends. OS's are smarter than that.

Comment: And it's not uncommon for subsequent runs of the app to then allocate at the very same address - seen this in debugging many times.

Comment: On top of that, each instance of the program gets its own *virtual* address space. Assuming two copies of the program are running, address `0x28fe98` on copy #1 and address `0x28fe98` on copy number #2 are **NOT** the same address.

Answer (score 1):

A memory leak is normally associated with a process. When the process terminates, its memory resources are reclaimed by the operating system.

That said, the [Wikipedia article on Memory Leaks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak#Consequences) says this:

> Leaks that are much more serious can occur...* Where running on an
>   operating system that does not automatically release memory on program
>   termination. Often on such machines if memory is lost, it can only be
>   reclaimed by a reboot, an example of such a system being AmigaOS.

However, such a phenomenon is not likely to occur with modern mainstream operating systems.

Comment: So if I am releasing the memory just before the program ends it's a waste of code-lines?

Comment: There shouldn't be any adverse consequences regarding the host OS. However, I would consider ignoring the clean-up of allocated memory not a good coding practice. Also consider that you may later modify the program and lose track of the fact that you did not free the memory of interest in the initial version. Regardless, if you do something like this for expediency, you should make a notation in your code with big bold letters: `// ==> MEMORY LEAK <==`.

Answer (score 0):

Terminating the program will tell the OS to free up any memory allocated by your program.

Apparently, it chose the same memory address to allocate for your use in the subsequent run.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the address of variable while the new returns you a address..you should print a

i.e.

```
cout << a << endl;
```

To clarify a little more what you see is a compiler generated offset(which is the offset to where the process is loaded) so it does not even depend on where the process is loaded. The start address of the process is stored in register in the processor.

I think you will see a different address if you add another declaration before it.

like

```
int b=0;

int * a = new int[1];
```

Now you should see the change when you recompile and run you should see a different address.But as a matter of fact that may not be intention in any case.

Comment: You're correct however your "answer" does not address the question, so it should be posted as a comment, not an answer. Note that someone else has already posted this as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If the program was ended, the memory is no longer reserved for that program.  Of course, the pointer won't always point to that memory address, it just happens to every time you have run it so far.  If you open some more programs and then run it again, the address will probably change.